# Removed data points in geom_bar histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I’m new to R, but learning all I can. I receive the message below when plotting a facetted density plot histogram.

> Warning message: Removed ### rows containing missing values
>   (geom_bar).

I’ve read the message may be due to an x-axis issue not showing all data points, however, after investigation it doesn’t appear so.

The error seems to be in the "position = "fill" " section of the geom_histogram. When the position = "fill"  is removed no errors are produced.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(recividism = sample(0:2, 100, replace = T),
                 TotalDays = sample(15:1000, 100, replace = T),
                 NumEnroll = sample(1:7, 100, replace = T))

df$recividism <- as.factor(df$recividism)

levels(df$recividism) <- c("Not Perm", "Perm", "Rec")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = TotalDays)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = recividism), position = "fill" ) + 
  facet_grid(facets = NumEnroll ~ .)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, I agree. Clearly, there is no real missing data. And as you said, if you `stack` instead of `fill`, all is fine.

What is happening, is that `ggplot` internally makes a table for each x by group (color in this case) by facet combination. In the case of `stack`, the combinations without any values are silently not plotted. This is because they stack up to zero. But for `fill` there is a division by the total, and since the total is 0 the answers would be `Inf`, but are set to `NA` instead.

You can see this:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = TotalDays)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = recividism), position = "fill" ) + 
  facet_grid(facets = NumEnroll ~ .)

head(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]], 10)
```

Shows:

> ```
>       fill  y count         x      xmin      xmax     density ncount ndensity PANEL group ymin ymax colour size linetype alpha
> 1  #619CFF NA     0  33.86207  16.93103  50.79310 0.000000000      0   0.0000     1     3   NA   NA     NA  0.5        1    NA
> 2  #00BA38 NA     0  33.86207  16.93103  50.79310 0.000000000      0   0.0000     1     2   NA   NA     NA  0.5        1    NA
> 3  #F8766D NA     0  33.86207  16.93103  50.79310 0.000000000      0   0.0000     1     1   NA   NA     NA  0.5        1    NA
> 4  #619CFF NA     0  67.72414  50.79310  84.65517 0.000000000      0   0.0000     1     3   NA   NA     NA  0.5        1    NA
> 5  #00BA38 NA     0  67.72414  50.79310  84.65517 0.000000000      0   0.0000     1     2   NA   NA     NA  0.5        1    NA
> 6  #F8766D NA     0  67.72414  50.79310  84.65517 0.000000000      0   0.0000     1     1   NA   NA     NA  0.5        1    NA
> 7  #619CFF  1     1 101.58621  84.65517 118.51724 0.007382892      1 135.4483     1     3    0    1     NA  0.5        1    NA
> 8  #00BA38  1     0 101.58621  84.65517 118.51724 0.000000000      0   0.0000     1     2    1    1     NA  0.5        1    NA
> 9  #F8766D  1     0 101.58621  84.65517 118.51724 0.000000000      0   0.0000     1     1    1    1     NA  0.5        1    NA
> 10 #619CFF NA     0 135.44828 118.51724 152.37931 0.000000000      0   0.0000     1     3   NA   NA     NA  0.5        1    NA
> ```

You can see there's `NA`s for `y` in many rows, and that is where you get the warning from.

Hope that clears things up a bit. And so it turns out that it does indeed happen because you don't have data for some levels of x. But that's not the full story.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just for clarification, if there is no information to display of a category within the facet and bin then a NA is displayed in the table created from the base data used to plot the filled histogram. Next, when plotting the facetted histogram ggplot strips all NAs from the table.... and this is what is called as "missing" or "removed" values?

Comment: Technically, they're not histograms, not otherwise correct yes!